# Delete Operator Confusion

Tags: javascript

So I found this technique as a workaround for a global .remove() method in all browsers.

`a.outerHTML =''; delete a`

a = your element.

My issue.. this is very confusing to me because it only works if I use outerHTML = '';.  But, the delete operator says here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete  It's only for deleting a property from a object? So, (this might be a silly question), but when setting a.outerHTML does that convert it into a deletable object then? How?

Edit: I almost feel like I should delete this question because it may sound so stupid, but I am evidently lost :P

Comment: Assigning an `innerHTML` property changes precisely nothing: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a9z0tzge/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delete` operator is for deleting properties from an object.

```
var obj = {x: true};
console.log(obj)    // {x: true}
delete obj.x;
console.log(obj);   // {}
```

I'd strongly recommend this reference: [Understanding `delete`](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)

---

In your example:

```
a.outerHTML =''; 
delete a;
```

The `delete` operator has nothing to do with the effect of `a.outerHTML = '';`  That `outerHTML` line of code is acting on its own to replace portions of the DOM with some new HTML.  Remove the `delete a` and the first line of code will still have the effect on the DOM you see.

---

In fact, in ES5 strict mode:

```
delete a;
```

will throw a SyntaxError.  That's how unintended that behavior is.

Comment: Yeah, but it works on elements though (if you do outerHTML=''), which is confusing me because they are not technically in a object right?

For example, If I just did delete a without setting the outerHTML = '', it won't delete. Why is that? What is outerHTML doing to it that makes it so special? Does it temporary convert it into a property then to an object (that's why delete works?)

Comment: When you  do `a.outerHTML = "";`, the effect of that has absolutely nothing to do with the `delete` operator.  That is changing a block of HTML which will necessarily change what elements are in the DOM.  This is similar to how `x.innerHTML = "<div>foo</div>";` will remove the current children of `x` and create new DOM objects in their place.  None of this has anything to do with the `delete` operator.

Comment: @NiCkNewman: all the action is from the `outerHTML` getter/setter, not the `delete` keyword.

Comment: Oh wow. Yeah, I just removed delete a and my script is doing the exact same thing. LOL wow. I knew I had a weird feeling about why is this delete operator even here.   (I'll checkout that page as well @jfriend00) 

Thank you!